# How can I use two velodyne(VLP16) together at the same time?

Tags: ros, vlp-16, vlp16, multiple, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a question about operating two velodyne laser sensors (VLP 16).

I’m a ROS and Ubuntu beginner. So, even if my question is inexperienced, please understand me and answer as in detail as possible. Thank you in advance.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo. I’m trying to operate two velodyne laser sensors – VLP 16 simultaneously in one laptop. I designate IP of each sensors as 192.168.1.201 and 192.168.1.202. I fixed my laptop Ethernet IP as 192.168.1.77 to coincide bandwidth(?); I mean the third number of IP address like 192.168.”1”.77. I made two sensors connect to my laptop using hub. I use Velodyne package and modified “VLP16_points.launch” in velodyne_pointcloud folder and “nodelet manager.launch” in velodyne_drvier folder to operate at the same time.

In nodelet_manager.launch of velodyne_driver folder, I attached `<arg name=”device_ip” default=”” />` under the source code `<arg name=”model” default=”VLP16” />` and `<param name=”device_ip” value=”$(arg device_ip)” />` under the source code `<arg name=”frame_id” default=”veldyne” />`

In VLP16_points.launch of velodyne_pointcloud folder, I made the source code as two group and tried to operate independently. First group is defined `<group ns = “ns1”></group>` and second group is defined `<group ns = “ns2”></group>`. The difference of two group’s source code is the only “device_ip”. I defined `<arg name = “device_ip” value = “192.168.1.201”/>` in first group and `<arg name = “device_ip” value = “192.168.1.202”/>` in second group. I thought because I designated the IPs differently it had to be implemented independently. But it was not.

I ran VLP16_points.launch and rviz , and topic of Pointcloud2 in rviz was presented /ns1/velodyne_points, /ns2/velodyne_points. As I pick the topic: /ns1/velodyne_points, pointcloud of two VLP16s appear simultaneously with regardless of IP address. I tried changing sensors’ IP and “device_ip” of VLP16_points.launch and nodelet_manager.launch. But regardeless of these change, pointcloud in rviz was appeared at the same time in topic /ns1/velodyne_points which is the topic of first group in VLP16_points.launch. When I pick the topic as /ns2/velodyne_points, no pointcloud appears. The terminal presents “bind: Address already in use” The Notice was not showed when I run only one VLP16. I hope to use the pointcloud independently to apply tf to sensors independently.

There were also other attempts in similar ways like operating two same launches which has “different device_ip”. But it also shows same result.

Thank you for reading this long question.

Have a nice day.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242475/how-can-i-use-two-velodyne(vlp16)-together-at-the-same-time?/) by [Low Frequency](https://answers.ros.org/users/27829/low-frequency/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JeongJae0815](https://answers.ros.org/users/28172/jeongjae0815/) on 2016-10-06**:
Hi, I'm trying to use two VLP16 at one computer. I have same problems with you. Did you solve this kind of a problem? If you do that, How did you solve it? Thank you in advance

**Comment by [EricD](https://answers.ros.org/users/28925/ericd/) on 2016-12-30**:
The Velodynes broadcast, so they are all spamming the same port unless you change it on each device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem is running the driver twice in a single `velodyne_nodelet_manager` process.

We probably ought to incorporate the frame_id into the nodelet manager name name. Please [open a github issue](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/new) to get this resolved.

**EDIT**: to provide more detail, this command in `velodyne_driver/launch/nodelet_manager.launch` should be changed:

```
 <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="driver_nodelet"
       args="load velodyne_driver/DriverNodelet velodyne_nodelet_manager" >
```

Instead of `velodyne_nodelet_manager` we should call it `$(arg frame_id)_nodelet_manager`, running the driver for each device in a separate process. Other nodelet loading to `velodyne_nodelet_manager` should similarly be changed. The node name may also need to be parameterized.

**EDIT 2**: there was a bug in the provided launch files, now fixed in the master source. See [ros-drivers/velodyne#108](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/108) for details.

Note that you need to configure the two devices to have different tf frames, IP addresses and UDP port numbers.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Low Frequency](https://answers.ros.org/users/27829/low-frequency/) on 2016-08-29**:
[https://github.com/JohnJungHwanYoo/Multiple_Velodyne_ING/tree/master/Multiple_velodynes]
As I told you before,only a few sources in nodelet_manager.launch and VLP16_points.launch are changed.In my github,VLP16_points.launch is the original launch file,my modified launch file is VLP16_points2.launch

**Comment by [JeongJae0815](https://answers.ros.org/users/28172/jeongjae0815/) on 2016-10-06**:
Hi, I'm trying to use two VLP16 at one computer. I have same problems with you. Did you solve this kind of a problem? If you do that, How did you solve it? Thank you in advance

**Comment by [Low Frequency](https://answers.ros.org/users/27829/low-frequency/) on 2017-02-10**:
Thank you for your kind answers. As I follow your directions, the sensors work independently! Setting the UDP port numbers was the critical point. I didn't try applying the coordinate problem. But I think I can proceed well. Thank you again!